# Qt QComboBox with different background color for each item?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there a way to set a different background color for each item in a `QComboBox` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the only way to do it would be to write your own model, inheriting `QAbstractListModel`, reimplementing `rowCount()`and `data()` where you can set the background color for each item (using the `BackgroundRole` role).

Then, use `QComboBox::setModel()` to make the `QComboBox` display it.

Here is a simple example, where I created my own list model, inheriting `QAbstractListModel` :

```
class ItemList : public QAbstractListModel
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   ItemList(QObject *parent = 0) : QAbstractListModel(parent) {}

   int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const { return 5; }
   QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
      if (!index.isValid())
          return QVariant();

      if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
         return QColor(QColor::colorNames().at(index.row()));

      if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
          return QString("Item %1").arg(index.row() + 1);
      else
          return QVariant();
   }
};
```

It is now easy to use this model with the combo box :

```
comboBox->setModel(new ItemList);
```